# Idiom or one word for people who ignore attempts to get in touch?

Tags: idiom-requests

I just read this question

[I need one-word expression for "Ignoring someone intentionally"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118091/i-need-one-word-expression-for-ignoring-someone-intentionally)

and am looking for something similar, an idiom or one word I think I have heard many times in sitcoms and shows aimed at adolescents.

Situation: two people, A and B, have been on a date. Afterwards A wants to, and B doesn't want to, meet again. A calls/texts/IMs B and B just ignores (or blocks) these contact attempts rather than telling A that (s)he has no interest in further contact.

Comment: I think I am looking for "the silent treatment" but I appreciate other suggestions.

Comment: Idiomatically, giving someone the *cold-shoulder*

Comment: Then use the idiom 'silent treatment' if you like it.

Comment: To 'blank' : _British slang : to behave in an unfriendly way toward (someone you have been friendly with in the past) : to ignore or refuse to talk to (someone)_  [Learners Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/blank)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ghosting**

Google dictionary defines it as:

> the practice of ending a personal relationship with someone by suddenly and without explanation withdrawing from all communication.
>   "I thought ghosting was a horrible dating habit reserved for casual flings"

It's a relatively new term and seems to have emerged to describe communications specifically including social media.

"The silent treatment" and "the cold shoulder" are more akin to "sulking" and imply (to me) a temporary cessation of communication with a friend, whereas ghosting seems more permanent and to apply to short term relationships.

Comment: Ghosting was the word I was looking for. Thank you.